# Windows Media Center won't Play MSN Video Player

Tags: windows, windows-media-center, media

My install of Windows Media Center won't play MSN Video Player videos. They appear in the main guide, but when I click on them, nothing happens.

If I look on the main menu, I don't have any icons for MSN Video player there.

People have suggested I try downloading updates, but that makes no difference.

I have internet connectivity. My region is set to the UK (which is where I am). If I navigate to the MSN Video Player using Internet Explorer, the videos play fine. The machine is an Acer Revo RL100, running Windows 7 64-bit.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some luck with this. The ProgramData\Microsoft\eHome directory (or equivalent on your version of Windows) contains a file called mcepg1-5.0.db, which looks to me like it stores all of the configuration for Windows Media Center.

I took a backup of this file, then removed it. When I started WMC again, the MSN Video Player option had reappeared on the menu. I was then able to set up Internet TV with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

See if you have Microsoft Silverlight. If so, disable it using *Tools* and *Manage Add-ons*.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I'll vote you up as it's a better solution than mine, but as I have got things working, I can't confirm whether your answer is correct!